# AWS Lambda - S3 put_object Invalid type for parameter Body

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a hosted zone in route 53 and would like to have the contents of the **hostzone** object stored in S3 but I am getting an error. I am thinking Body is the correct parameter but maybe this is because the object is in JSON format?

```
import boto3
import json

def allwork():
    client = boto3.client('route53')
    hostzone = client.list_hosted_zones()
    bucket_name = "testlambda"
    file_name = "r53data.txt"
    lambda_path = "/tmp/" + file_name
    s3_path = "10102018/" + file_name 

    s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
    s3.Bucket(bucket_name).put_object(Key=s3_path, Body=hostzone)

allwork()
```

Here is the error:

```
module initialization error: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Body, value: {u'HostedZones': 
[{u'ResourceRecordSetCount': 7, u'CallerReference': '814E3.........
```

Comment: Are you sure this is in JSON format and not an object?

Comment: Not 100%, reviewing the docs over here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/route53.html#Route53.Client.list_hosted_zones

Comment: Looks like it returns a dict, so you need to json encode it manually before passing it to put_object.

Comment: Thanks it worked, updating to include your recommendation!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

tkausl answered the question in the comments:

```
Looks like it returns a dict, so you need to json encode it manually before passing it to put_object
```

update:

```
import boto3
import json

def allwork():
client = boto3.client('route53')
hostzone = client.list_hosted_zones()
bucket_name = "testlambda"
file_name = "r53data.txt"
lambda_path = "/tmp/" + file_name
s3_path = "10102018/" + file_name 

hostzone2=json.dumps(hostzone, ensure_ascii=False)

s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
s3.Bucket(bucket_name).put_object(Key=s3_path, Body=hostzone2)

allwork()
```

Comment: Please don't edit the solution into the question.  Future visitors looking at the question will assume that the code you are showing will generate the error, and of course it won't, because it's been fixed.  Leave the incorrect code in the question, and put the solution in the answer.